# AS3 - Turn &amp; to &

Tags: actionscript-3

How to turn characters such as `&amp; to &` or `&mdash; to —` with AS3? Is there something like HTML unescape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no built in library. So you have to write yourself, or you can use available solutions like [this](http://www.markledford.com/blog/2009/02/25/as3-htmldecode-htmlencode-xml-hack/).

Comment: we can use the htmlText and text property to convert HTML encoded text to normal char...

Comment: @Mrugesh, yes we can. I have seen your answer. But personally I won't like to create a text field when I only need string modification. But yes, that can be a solution too.